# how to check computer's state using Qt?

Tags: qt, networking

i'm trying to get computer's state in my LAN...
thought about using QTcpSocket but it's not realy effective since port also should be inserted as:

```
socket->connectToHost("hostName", portNumber);
if (socket->waitForConnected(1000))
     qDebug("Connected!");
```

can anyone demonstare me a better way to check if computer is responding ?

Comment: Are you trying to determine the connectivity of the local machine or that of a remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping)

```
int exitCode = QProcess::execute("ping", QStringList() << "-c1" << "hostname");
if (0 == exitCode) {
    // it's alive
} else {
    // it's dead
}
```

Arguments may vary. For example, I believe it would be `ping -n 1 "hostname"` on Windows. The example should work on most non-Windows versions.

Comment: Some firewalls will block that, and it takes an external system call.  That's certainly less than ideal.

Comment: Sorry, can't upvote any more. It looks to be the only reliable way to do it in Qt :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to check if your local machine is on the network or if a target machine is ?

There isn't a good cross platform way of doing this.
The nearest on qt is [QNetworkInterface](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qnetworkinterface.html), and check attribute "ISup" - it's not perfect, it may be active if you have a network cable connected but just to a router, and inactive if you have a 3G modem but aren't on a call.

On Windows check InternetGetConnectedState()

Answer (score -1):

One good way is just to verify that they can resolve domain names using [QHostInfo](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qhostinfo.html).  If they can then they likely have internet access:

```
QHostInfo::lookupHost("www.kde.org", this, SLOT(lookedUp(QHostInfo)));
```

Of course, you could just try to connect to the host as well, which is even better proof that everything is working correctly.  I would do it asynchronously rather than synchronously, but it's truly the best test.

Comment: The other machine could die and still have an active DNS entry.

Comment: Yes, and then it won't matter whether you can ping it or resolve the hostname.  In that case, as I said, the best way is to truly try to connect to it.