# How to ping a remote machine with Qt

Tags: qt, ping

I am developping a cross-platform (Windows-Mac-Unix) application using Qt.
This is my first time using this framework so I am discovering it.

I need to ping a distant machine based on its IP address and I can't find a way to perform this task with the Qt framework, though it seems pretty basic...
I've found examples on the web but they use OS-dependant methods, which is precisely what I want to avoid since I have to run on different environments. Isn't there a simple ping command in the Qt framework? And how to use it?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check computer's state using Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601279/how-to-check-computers-state-using-qt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no direct way to ping another system in QT since it requires some superuser privileges in different Operating Systems. So the best way would be to try and establish a connection (preferably TCP)  between the two machines.