# QT with C++ GUI application to check Network Status

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, network-programming, ip-address

Well, I have been doing some experiment with QT lately, I have a touchscreen Linux PC and I connect it to the WiFi network. Instead of pinging a network old fashioned way I thought of making an app for it.

The interface is like, I would enter an IP address and the application will ping the network and let me know if the IP is ping-able or not. When the IP is getting pinged Green Check will be shown, if not getting pinged then Red Check will be shown.

My progress is, I am able to take the IP in a script file and ping it. But the problem is how to interface the ping reply with the application. i.e. the two labels (Green and Red Check) ???

Thanks in advance. My GUI looks like this.

[image]

Comment: the use is like I said, monitoring my network nodes on the move :) I just enter an IP and it shows if its UP or not. Sure you can run a normal ping command and there are a billion ready to use apps to do it for you. but still... ... ...

Comment: It seems you are right, the question indeed is duplicate. Wonder why it didn't show up during my posting the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a good cross platform way for doing this. But you can use platform specific ways :

On Linux you can :

```
int returnedCode = QProcess::execute("ping", QStringList() << "-c 1" << ui->ipEdit->text());
if (returnedCode == 0) 
{
    // It's active, Show Green Check
} else 
{
    //  It's dead, Show Red Check
}
```

On Windows it is like :

```
int returnedCode = QProcess::execute("ping", QStringList() << "-n" << "1" << ui->ipEdit->text());
if (returnedCode == 0) 
{
    // It's active, Show Green Check
} else 
{
    //  It's dead, Show Red Check
}
```

Comment: Trying it once is a bad idea. It is possible that the network is up, but one packet is lost somehow. I would say the minimum trial is three. Further nitpicking, "inactive" is a better name than "dead". The network might not be dead altogether, just inactive.

Comment: hey it solved my problem.. please let me know if there are any study materials regarding QT hands on learning.

Comment: specially on linux. Ubuntu Precise rocks.

Comment: @AmarjitBiswas: see also this post which seems to be almost the same. Albeit that is 4 years old, I think it is still valid: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2601352/2682142

Comment: indeed you are right. but it didn't show up during posting, wonder why.

Comment: @Nejat Can you please have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858376/creating-dmg-for-qt-app-mac-osx