# Creating .dmg for Qt app mac OSX

Tags: macos, qt, dmg

I see so many questions and posts asking about this, and almost everywhere I see the `op` being asked to refer to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html

But the problem for someone who is new to *Qt* is difficult to understand there how to generate the *dmg* file.

Let's not go in depth of having external libraries, plugins etc in a project.

If we create a totally new QWidget program, without a single line of code, the default project that just shows a window, then how will someone generate the *dmg* file.

If we do `macdeployqt yourProjectName.app -dmg` inside the `debug build` folder, without doing anything then it will of course create dmg file but it fails to open and now if you try to run the default project then will face this error :

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load 
the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: cocoa.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

So, what is the process of generating a *dmg* file for a Qt application?

Edit : Detailed discussion in here : https://forum.qt.io/topic/82746/creating-dmg-for-qt-app-mac-osx