# Ping request : hide console window and differentiate "not responding" from response : no response

Tags: windows, qt, ping

I'm making ping requests to all the server on my domain with Qt

I found inspiration here : [how to check computer's state using Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601279/how-to-check-computers-state-using-qt)

and did like this :

```
int exitCode = QProcess::execute("ping", QStringList() << "-n 1" << "hostname");
if (0 == exitCode) {
    // it's alive
} else {
    // it's dead
}
```

Its working (mostly)

But, here is two problem I can't find solution for :

When I launch, some ugly windows console show up for all the ping, how to hide them ?

Some server are known by the DNS but not working anymore : resulting in this message for a ping :

```
****************> ping oldserverNotWorkingAnymore
sending a 'ping' request for oldserverNotWorkingAnymore.mydomain [172.20.*.*] with 32 bytes of data
response from 172.20.*.* : Impossible to call host
response from 172.20.*.* : Impossible to call host
response from 172.20.*.* : Impossible to call host
response from 172.20.*.* : Impossible to call host

stat : send = 4, received = 4, lost = 0
```

which result in the program thinking the host exist while it's not

How to differentiate from a really working ping ?

Comment: Tagged windows you could `IcmpSendEcho2`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366051(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Did you try to start the process with `QProcess::start()`?

Comment: Definitely go with IcmpSendEcho-API if it does not need to be portable (notice: `ping -n X` is not portable anyway).